# virStorageFileBackendFileRead Failed to open file '/dev/...': Permission denied

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, libvirt

I'm trying to bring up a VM through `virsh define`, `virsh start`. The command doesn't show any errors and `virsh list` shows the VM is running. However, I can't access to the console, so I checked the libvirt log.

There are a few errors reporting:

```
virStorageFileBackendFileRead Failed to open file '/dev/...': Permission denied
```

The `/dev/`s are the logical volumes that I created. I already use `root` as user so I'm not sure what caused the permission error.

I saw this [thread](https://bugs.launchpad.net/apparmor/+bug/1825745) and it says this is related to apparmor. I tried to disable apparmor with `systemctl disable apparmor` but the permission error still remains. Any help would be appreciated.